# Declaring a variable in Javascript - Constructor vs Literal

Tags: javascript, variables

Watching a tutorial today I came across the following:

```
var q2Var1 = "hi there.",
    q2Var2 = String( "another string here." );
```

Is q2Var the "constructor notation" and q2Var the "literal notation" for declaring a variable, or am I not drawing the correct conclusion?

Thank you.

Comment: looks good to me, for costructor i think you want 'new String("")' the seconf one looks like a cast from a String literal to a string.

Comment: That constructor takes a literal!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, neither of those use a constructor to create a string object.

The first is just a string primitive, the second is a string primitive that is sent through the `String` conversion function, which will just return the string primitive unchanged.

---

The `String` conversion function is usually used to turn other things into string primitives, for example a number:

```
var s = String(42);
```

---

To create a `String` object you use the `new` keyword:

```
var s = new String("hi there.");
```

The `String` object has all the methods that you are used to use on a string, like the `length` property. The reason that you can use them on string primitives also, is that they are automatically converted to `String` objects when you use a method on them.

So, this:

```
var l = "asdf".length;
```

actually does the same as:

```
var l = new String("asdf").length;
```

---

The `String` conversion function always returns a string primitive, so if you have a `String` object, the function will turn it back into a string primitive:

```
var s = "asdf"; // typeof s returns "string"

var s = new String(s); // typeof s now returns "object"

s = String(s); // typeof s now returns "string"
```

Answer (score 0):

I never heard those names before, but 'constructor notation' would most likely be the q2Var2 one, since you're passing arguments to the constructor of String. It's not really important how you call them though, is it? :P

Comment: It's actually not the constructor, for that you would use `new String`.